# C++: How a class uses object as parameter

Tags: c++

```
class Agent
{
public:
   Agent() {}
   ~Agent() {}
   virtual bool Do() = 0;
};

class GameAgent : public Agent
{
public:
    GameAgent() {}
    ~GameAgent() {}
};
```

I would like to initialize this `GameAgent` like

```
GameAgent* m_pGameAgent = new GameAgent();
```

And I got this error message.

> Error  12  error C2259: 'GameAgent' : cannot instantiate abstract class

How I can I fix it? I can not change the structure of `Agent`.

Comment: The class shown above is not abstract, so that means the code you are compiling is not the code you have shown us. Please show code that causes that error, not some other, related code that doesn't produce the same error.

Comment: Post full or relevant code please. GameAgent is not abstract. Did you forget to add some pure virtual functions or some base class?

Comment: lol "let me add this code that completely changes everything". (And typo `public` with `pubic` because why not)

Comment: How much does a "pubic agent" cost?

Answer (score 3):

In the code you've posted, neither `GameAgent` nor `Agent` is abstract; so we must guess what's causing the error in your real code.

Assuming the real `Agent` is abstract (since you say it is), then `GameAgent` will have to override whatever pure virtual functions it declares, in order not to be abstract itself.

Answer (score 1):

By making class `GameAgent` not abstract.

Comment: That doesn't make a class abstract.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yeah, I thought so, that's why the error is absolutely puzzling (and most probably simply incomplete).

Answer (score 1):

I implement the Do in GameAgent, and solve it.
Thanks  to everyone